# What is the most common PKCS#12 format for Certificates used for SSL Applications?

Tags: ssl, certificate

As far as I know, PKCS#12 formats can store multiple certificates and private keys.

But, I would like to know what is the most common format in a PKCS#12 format? i.e. One End Entity Certificate, One private Key and all CAs for the End Entity Certificate till the root?

Which is the most common format used by SSL Applications like https servers etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really up to the user what he decides to store in PKCS#12 file. I.e. it can be either a certificate with a private key, or a certificate with a private key and some CA certificate(s) or just a certificate storage with many certificates. For example, our SecureBlackbox allows you to store any number of certificates (not necessarily with private keys) in PKCS#12 file. Most common usage scenario is exporting a certificate, it's private key and *sometimes* CA certificates to single PFX file for secure transport or export/import to another system.

Comment: From my experience, it's also a certificate, a private key and optionally the CA chain. That's the way browsers do for instance. One exception I know, is that Firefox allows you to export all your keys and certificates in one PKCS#12 file.